# write in a file with one function

Tags: php, file

Is there a function where I'm not constrained to open a file to write in it and then to close it up. I'm searching for one function looking like this

```
bool thefunction(string line, string path, string mode);
```

**line** is what I want to write in the file located from **path** and either from the end of the document or at the start erasing all the content defined with **mode** argument.
Ok this sounds a bit picky, but it's the idea. I want to make a count up and need a file to increment the value in it.

Comment: Even if you use `file_put_contents()` to write the incremented value to the file, that doesn't really help you avoid race conditions.  There will still be time between when you read the value in the file, and write the new value out.  You need a single atomic operation which reads the old value, increments it, and writes it back out.  The only way to do that with file IO is via `flock()`.  It'd actually be easier to just use memcached, which offers an atomic increment operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). You'll still need to `chmod()` the file if you require different permissions than `file_put_contents()` creates.

Example:

```
// This writes a line to a file, appending to what's already there
$success = file_put_contents("/path/to/file.txt", "This string goes into the file\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: The answer can't be shortened more... Thanks Michael

Comment: @Oddantfr Happy to help. As @Frank Farmer mentions above, it's not immune to race conditions though.